# C#-Error-does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments-I don't get what I am doing wrong?

Tags: c#, constructor, arguments

I keep trying to make this C# program work, but I keep getting an Error about the constructor taking 1 argument.  I don't get it.  I think it has to do with the " Test myTest = new Test(3);" but I don't know what to do with it.

Any help or steering me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

public class Test
{

    private int tally;

    public void Test(int start)
    {

        tally = start;

    }

    public void AddFive()
    {

        tally += 5;

    }

    public void Display()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("The tally is {0}", tally);

    }

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Test myTest = new Test(3);

        myTest.AddFive();

        myTest.Display ();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Oh man!!! You are having really OOP problem :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors don't have return type.
So instead of

```
public void Test(int start)
{

    tally = start;

}
```

you should have

```
 public Test(int start)
{

    tally = start;

}
```

Comment: I am an idiot.  Thanks a lot.  It never occurred to me that if the class was void, a return value wouldn't be given.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor definition you said to return void. That is not required. Your constrctor should be

```
public Test(int strat)
{
...
}
```